# Simulating a middle-button click on my touchpad often scrolls up the view

Tags: linux, debian, touchpad

At times, when I simulate the mouse middle-button with my touchpad, my view auto-scrolls towards the top. I've seen this on my browser and my X terminal.

Here's my touchpad settings:

```
$ synclient -l
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 38
    RightEdge               = 929
    TopEdge                 = 38
    BottomEdge              = 673
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 52
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 24
    HorizScrollDelta        = 24
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.166667
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 0
    RBCornerButton          = 0
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 0
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 2
    ClickFinger3            = 1
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 1
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 6
    VertHysteresis          = 6
    ClickPad                = 0
```

Comment: Which parameters make it so that the touchpad can simulate a middle mouse button? I've never seen a touchpad configured that way.

Comment: I ran `synclient ClickFinger2=2` for that to happen. Note, however, the problem seems to have nothing to do with that setting since it happens even after I run `synclient ClickFinger2=0`.

Comment: @slm Depending on the hardware model and on the software settings, either tap a corner or tap two fingers.